# Edges of CGAL hyperbolic Delaunay triangulation

Tags: c++, cgal, delaunay

I'm trying to do a hyperbolic Delaunay triangulation with CGAL. Below is my code. `Rcpp` is a library to use C++ with R.

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2<K> HDtt;
typedef HDtt::Point_2 HPoint;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<
  CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2<HDtt>,
  CGAL::Hyperbolic_triangulation_face_base_2<HDtt>>
HTds;
typedef CGAL::Hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulation_2<HDtt, HTds> HDt;

Rcpp::IntegerMatrix htest(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix points) {
  std::vector<HPoint> hpts;
  const unsigned npoints = points.ncol();
  hpts.reserve(npoints);
  for(unsigned i = 0; i != npoints; i++) {
    const Rcpp::NumericVector pt = points(Rcpp::_, i);
    hpts.emplace_back(HPoint(pt(0), pt(1)));
  }
  HDt hdt;
  hdt.insert(hpts.begin(), hpts.end());
  const size_t nedges = hdt.number_of_hyperbolic_edges();
  Rcpp::IntegerMatrix Edges(2, nedges);
  size_t i = 0;
  for(HDt::All_edges_iterator ed = hdt.all_edges_begin();
      ed != hdt.all_edges_end(); ++ed) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector edge_i(2);
    HDt::Vertex_handle sVertex = ed->first->vertex(HDt::cw(ed->second));
    edge_i(0) = sVertex->id();
    HDt::Vertex_handle tVertex = ed->first->vertex(HDt::ccw(ed->second));
    edge_i(1) = tVertex->id();
    Edges(Rcpp::_, i) = edge_i;
    i++;
  }
  return Edges;
}
```

I feed this function with some points in the unit circle. Then it returns an integer matrix, which is supposed to be the edges, but all entries of the matrix I get are equal to a huge integer instead. I also tried `std::cout << sVertex->id()` and this prints this huge integer.

Comment: I see, **Triangulation_vertex_base_with_id_2** requires to enter the ids.

Answer (score 2):

There are isolated edges because the authors choose to filter out triangles whose circumscribing circle is "not compact" (i.e., it is not included in the Poincaré disk).

See the user manual
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Hyperbolic_triangulation_2/index.html#HT2_Euclidean_and_hyperbolic_Delaunay_triangulations
" A Euclidean Delaunay face is hyperbolic if its circumscribing circle is contained in ℍ2. "

For more details: https://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/view/2926

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm a bit surprised, I always thought that a hyperbolic triangle is nothing but three joined points in a hyperbolic space. Is it standard to reserve this word for the triangles satisfying the property you mention?

Comment: This is about the _Delaunay property_ for triangles, not about the definition of triangles. 
We chose to only consider compact disks for the Delaunay property. This is the whole point of the algorithm (see the paper). 
Compact disks are sometimes considered in the literature. 

If you also want triangles with empty on-compact circumscribing disks, you can just take the Euclidean Delaunay triangulation underlying the hyperbolic one. 
Then for pictures, you only need to replace Euclidean line segments by hyperbolic segments. That's it.

Comment: A fix on my previous comment
"Compact disks are sometimes considered in the literature." 
---> I meant: "Non-compact disks are sometimes considered in the literature."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way. One has to set the ids, they were unset and that's why I got a huge integer. Also one has to take the vertices of the triangulation, because while these are the same as the input vertices, they are in another order.

```cpp
  ......
  HDt hdt;
  hdt.insert(hpts.begin(), hpts.end());
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix Vertices(2, npoints);
  int index = 0;
  for(HDt::All_vertices_iterator vd = hdt.all_vertices_begin();
      vd != hdt.all_vertices_end(); ++vd){
    vd->id() = index;
    HPoint pt = vd->point();
    Vertices(0, index) = pt.x();
    Vertices(1, index) = pt.y();
    index++;
  }
  ......
```

However I don't know why there is an isolated edge:

[image]